# I'm new to Ubuntu. How do I access my SD Card?

Tags: sd-card

I'm doing an arduino project involving file writes/read from an SD Card. My workplace runs on Ubuntu.

When I insert my SD card (it's really an adapter for my Micro SD card), nothing appears under "Devices" in the Files launcher. Is there a way to access it like I would on Windows from My Computer?

Comment: Does the card work on other machines ? Could it be corrupt ?

Answer (score 0):

-Reboot with the SD card in the slot.

-Do a PCI re-scan

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

for more details visit [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/995743)

Comment: Why down vote for the answer if anyone having other answer than add your comment

Answer (score -1):

You access drives from a *File Manager*, which you probably know as Windows Explorer or Finder, depending on the operating system you are coming from.

Without knowing specifics of your system, you can probably open the file manager by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `nautilus` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  The drives will be listed on the left.